# Android Bluetooth auto reconnect

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

Android Bluetooth re-connection is not happening. I was using the Android BluethoothChat sample app in 2 mobiles (HTC desire & Samsung galaxy s). after pairing 1st time it's working fine it's connected and able to send & receive data. but when one of device lost connection not able to re-connect the same device. After connection lost I stopped the BluethoothChatService and started again but it's not connected with other device.

1) start application both the side - connected automatically (Working fine)

2) **Connection lost in any one side - reconnect not happening**

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android-apps/2.1_r2/com/example/android/BluetoothChat/BluetoothChat.java